# php relocate when user logged in

Tags: php

Currently creating a html sign in form consisting of a email address and password saved in a file called index.php.

Above my `<html>` tag I've created relevant php scripts to check whether the information provided matches that of what is saved in my database.

After a small number of if statements, I'm trying to use the header() function redirect the user to a new page.

Though, this doesn't seem to be working and I'm pretty stuck for why.

My HTML form -> `form action='index.php'` which directs itself to itself, so I'm not sure if that is potentially causing an error?

My HTML:

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST"> 
    <table style="width:100%"> 
        <tr> 
            <th><input type="text" name="email" required placeholder="Email" /></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><input type="password" name="password" required placeholder="Password" /></th>
        </tr>
            <tr>
        <th> <input class="button" id="sign-in-show" type="submit" value="Sign in" name="submit" /> </th>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
            <th> <p style="float:right; font-size:13px; margin-top:0px;"> <a href="">Forgot password?</a> </p> </th>
        </tr>           
    </table>
</form>
```

I'll also post all my php code, as only posting my header() code seems a bit pointless:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password); 

        if($conn->connect_error) { 
            die ('Connection Failed'); 
        } else { 
            echo ('Connection Established <br>'); 

            if(!mysqli_select_db($conn,'Oreon')) { 
                die('Database could not be reached ' . $conn->error); 
            } else { 

                // First get the row containing the email address provided 
                $sign_in_token = "SELECT * FROM core_customer_information WHERE email='".$email."' LIMIT 1"; 

                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sign_in_token); 

                // Check if the query has returned a row 
                if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) 
                { 
                    // Store needed variables 
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
                    { 
                        $tempPassword = $row['password'];
                        $checkActivation = $row['activated']; 

                        // Check if the account has been activated 
                        if($checkActivation=='0') 
                        { 
                            die('Your account has not yet been activated');
                        } 

                        // Check if password matches hashed crypted password 
                        else if (password_verify($user_password, $tempPassword)) 
                        {
                            $_SESSION['sessionEmail'] = $email;
                            header('Location: http://www.google.com'); 
                            exit(); 
                        }
                    }
                } 

                else 
                { 
                    die ("Incorrect email address or password: " . $conn->error); 
                }
            } // close brackets db selected 
        }
    }
```

At the moment, I'm just trying to redirect to Google just for testing purposes.

Would appreciate if someone could help me.

Thanks in advance (and sorry for having to post all of my code)

Comment: Have you checked your error logs? You're making an assumption the query is working.

Comment: Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a very common error to read code with include, or require, functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem exists when using a single PHP/HTML file. [source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: Ah lifesaver @ManosForsaken I was echoing something out. Thanks for that. Much appreciated!!!!